# How to stop Visual Studio on Mac breaking on exceptions

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, appium, visual-studio-mac

**Short Version**

Can I tell Visual Studio 2019 for Mac to stop breaking on exceptions? It's very annoying

**Long Version**
I am using Visual Studio 2019 on a Mac. I'm trying to run some Appium automation in debug mode. I'm using the Appium Wait command to wait until an element is visible on screen, so that I know the page has loaded. I have the Wait inside a try catch block, so that when it fails and throws an exception I can just ignore it, as it will keep failing until either the time I set has elapsed or the element has loaded on the page.

The problem is that when I'm running in debug mode Visual Studio will stop and tell me about this exception every single time and it is very annoying. I can't find a way to tell VS to just ignore it and let me carry on. On Windows there is a simple tick box on the exception pop up window to tell it to ignore it, but I can find no such option on VS for the Mac.

Can anybody help please?

Thanks

[image]